# Jquery when I use on() function it block my site

Tags: jquery

This is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.post_box').on('click', function(e) { 
        jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click");
    });  
});
```

When I click on the div `post_box` it trigger a link (pop up greybox)located in sub div of `post_box` which has the class `read_more,` right now it work good but the problem when I close the link `greybox`, and click again on the div `post_box` it doesn't work, I have to refresh the page to click it.

If I put the `on()` function instead , on the first click it will trigger the link and get blocked, I think it trigger the link more than one because of the sub divs this is the HTML code

```
<div class="post_box" >
    <div class="post_box_top">
        <div class="post_box_center">
            <div class="post_box_content">

                <div class="post_date">

                </div>
                <div class="post_content">

              <?php   echo   $content_post = get_post(get_the_ID());?>

                </div>
                <div class="post_footer">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="read_more"  rel="gb_pageset[search_sites]"  data-greybox-type="iframe">Read more</a>
               // this the link i should trigger when someone click on the <div class="post_box">   
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

http://ec2-107-22-235-75.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ take a look here please, this the site with function `one()` in case I change to `on()` when you click on div it block http://haiders.imcserver.ro/telugu you can take a look at the second case with `on()` here.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

This is a issue of event propagation: when triggering click event of your link, the event is triggered as well on the parent .post_box, causing the loop. See [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

The following should fix the issue:

```
jQuery('.read_more').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

---

Did you try simply with [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.post_box').click(function() { 
         jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click");
    });  
});
```

Comment: actually i want when some click on the parent .post_box it pop-up, and i think you have the right there is a loop,  i put the code like this but it doesn't work  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
 
jQuery('.post_box').on('click', function(e) {


     e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click");
   

 
});
}); is there something wrong

Comment: The stopPropagation() function should be called on the .read_more class.
It doesn't stop the propagation of the actual user's click event, but the one from the javascript
    `jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click"); `

Try to copy/paste what I wrote.